# List stored files using HTTP

Tags: 13.04, server, apache2, webserver, mediaserver

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux based OS and I wonder if someone know a program or a way to list all the files in a folder on my server when I'm using a webbrowser and visiting the Ubuntu Server. Almost the same thing as using FTP and a webbrowser but I want to be able to use HTTP/S and I will not be able to edit or download files. Just read the file names in a folder located at `/home/user/downloads`

Have been looking for hours now and can't find a way to do it couse I don't really know what to search for. If anyone could help me, i would really appreciate it!

I currently got Apache2, OpenSSH, LFTP installed.

Greetings,
David

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a setting in apache configuration and is called "Directory Listings".

You can use ...

```
<Directory /var/www/html/documents/>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

to make a directory listing for "/var/www/html/documents/".

You can use ...

```
IndexIgnore *tmp
```

to exclude files ending in tmp.

A special header and footer can be created with ...

```
HeaderName header.html
ReadmeName footer.html
```

You can also use styling with ...

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable
IndexStyleSheet /css/autoindex.css
```

In you installation there should be an example inside (it also shows how to add icons to a listing):

```
./conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
```

Also see ...

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Here is a custom directory ...

- http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is posible to show the files from /home/user or does it have to go through the "www" directory?

Comment: You should be able to add any directory butsecurity wise I would not add /home/$USER

Comment: You could also use a symbolic link from /var/www/html/somename to the /home/user/folder you want to show. But I have to agree with Rinzwind, it isn't secure. Also, Apache lets you download all those files! You may want to look into using at least a BasicAuth and HTTPS to protect that feature...